# Hide fixed element when past another

Tags: javascript, html, fixed

Here is a small demo:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-empty"></div>
    <ul>
        <div id="divfix"><li id="lifix">Text 1 FIXED</li></div>
        <div id="divfix2"><li id="lifix2">Text 2 FIXED</li></div>
        <div id="divfix3"><li id="lifix3">Text 3 FIXED</li></div>
    </ul>
    <div class="container-footer"></div>
</body>
```

**JSCRIPT**

```
var toppag=$("#lifix,#lifix2,#lifix3");
var pag=$("#divfix,#divfix2,#divfix3");

toppag.css({position:"relative"});


$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll=$(this).scrollTop();
    pag.each(function(i,n){
        if(scroll < $(this).offset().top) {
            toppag.eq(i).css({'position':'relative'});
        }
        if(scroll > ($(this).offset().top + toppag.eq(i).height()))  {
            toppag.eq(i).css({'position':'fixed',"top":"0"});
        }
    }); 
});
```

DEMO HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/Kigris/4cb0ygun/2/

I want to hide "Text 1 FIXED" when reaches "Text 2 FIXED" and so on. Also, when all reach the footer hide them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
 var footer = $(".container-footer");
 pag.css('position', 'relative'); under toppage.css etc
```

and

```
 if(scroll > footer.offset().top){
    toppag.hide();
 }else{ toppag.show();}
```

and

```
toppag.eq(i-1).parent().css({'z-index':"0"});
```

in your second if(scroll)

What this does is makes sure the fixed element gets pushed to the bottom in stacking order.

DEMO: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fuv08k9v/1/)

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot sir!